# Change item for AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use `AVQueuePlayer` to stream a playlist and want to be able to select songs from a `UITableView` displaying the items in the list.

I tried just reloading the player each time an item is selected, but I get `An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer`

`itemArray` is the full item list.
Index of the table item `clicked = playIndex.`

```
 [player removeAllItems];
    player=nil;
    NSMutableArray *currentItemArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:itemArray];
    for(int i=0;i<playingIndex; i++)
    {
        [currentItemArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }

        player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:currentItemArray];
[player play]
```

*Also, is there a better way to remove those objects without iterating? I couldn't figure out removeObjectsAtIndexes

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your problem is exactly, but what you want to do is use `[player insertItem:afterItem:]` to dynamically modify the playlist. Similarly, use `removeItem` to remove items dynamically from the playlist.

To remove objects from an array until `playingIndex`:

```
[currentItemArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,playingIndex)];
```

Comment: say I've clicked on a song thats number 6 on the playlist. I remove the first 5 items. But then I click on item 2 (which has been removed from the playqueue items. Then would you add back the other items? Seems messy....It would be easier I think to just reassign the player, but it doesn't seem to work. Sorry, I'm not good at explaining myself.

Comment: You have a tableview with a list of songs. You want the player to start playing all those songs sequentially, but you want to allow the user to select a specific song and have the player jump to it? And when the song ends, what does the player do?

Comment: Goes to the song below it in the table...like an iPod

Comment: Yes then it's significantly easier logic-wise to simply recreate the currentItemArray, remove the items you don't want using my above code, and recreate the player queue with that array. Otherwise you're going to have to check whether the item the user wants is still in the queue or not, then advance to it if it is, otherwise recreate the queue anyway.

Comment: Right. But, then I get that AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer ..any ideas on how to handle that?

Comment: You need to paste the relevant code where you link the queue to the player.